# Nodejs node-ews packge Missing dependency ntlm-client when using version 3.5.0

Tags: node.js, exchange-server, exchangewebservices, ntlm, node-ews

Hi I'm trying to use node-ews package to send emails in nodejs backend, when I used the version 3.4.2
of node-ews it's work fine but with some vulnerabilities (lodash and httpntlm ), I tried to use the newest version of this package witch is 3.5.0 and I unfortunately I get an error missing client-ntlm package, I added manually in my package.json but I get an error { code: 9001, msg: 'The server didnt respond properly', result: null }

Install new version of node-ews 3.5.0 ==> getting messing package client-ntlm ==> install client-ntlm ==> error : The server didnt respond properly

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you ran the

```
npm install
```

command after adding the package to package.json file.

```
"dependencies": {
    [...]
    "node-ews": "^3.5.0",
    "ntlm-client": "^0.1.1",
    [...]
  },
```

Or alternatively, you can simply run the

```
npm install ntlm-client
```

Both commands are from the console from the project root.

This should fix your issue.